# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{4^n})$

Tags: summation

I want to calculate the infinite summation below :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{4^n})$$

but I totally failed to approach.

Thanks for any help.

Wolframalpha gave me the results : $\ln(3/2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n,\qquad |x|<1,
$$ which may be obtained by integrating termwise
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,\qquad |x|<1.
$$

Comment: I've missed such a very elementary point. Thanks!

Comment: @JinmooYou are very welcome.